# How to save a variable from a tkinter entry without global?

Tags: python, class, tkinter

I wrote a code for my the student council elections and wanted to improve it with a GUI. I managed to display the value entered in the entry but I don't understand why "a" isn't outputted, `App.TutorGroup = text` should change the variable. I don't want to use `global` because I heard that it's a bad habit to use it.

```py
import tkinter as tk


class App:
    TutorGroup = ""
    def __init__(self, root):
        root.title("App")
        root.geometry("500x250")

        self.entryy = tk.Entry(root, text="What is the name of the tutor group, eg. 7B ", width=50)
        self.entryy.pack()
        
        self.button = tk.Button(root, text="Enter", width=5, height=5, command=self.button_command)
        self.button.pack()
        
        self.labell=tk.Label(root, text = "", width=70, height=25)
        self.labell.pack()
        
         
        if App.TutorGroup != "":
            print("a")
        

    def button_command(self):
        text = self.entryy.get()
        self.labell["text"] = text
        App.TutorGroup = text
        
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your `if` statement executes about a millisecond after you created the widgets, so the user hasn't had a chance to enter any data.

Comment: @BryanOakley i see, so where should I put it to make it print a?

Comment: Put it in `button_command`

Comment: Or add a second button that displays what was entered.

Comment: @Barmar the whole point of the question is trying to redefine TutorGroup and access its content outside of button_command without using global

Comment: Why is that a problem? Add a second button, and in its command function put `print(App.TutorGroup)`

Comment: _"the whole point of the question is trying to redefine TutorGroup and access its content outside of button_command without using global "_ - your code seems to be doing that. Once `button_command` has run, you can access `App.TutorGroup` and it will have the new value.

Comment: @BryanOakley great, my code was doing what i wanted it to do. I simply didn't know because I though that the if statement would loop with all the rest

Comment: _"I though that the if statement would loop with all the rest"_ - I don't know what you mean by that. None of the code "loops", except the call to `mainloop`.